# Can you decrypt storage from an Android phone directly from the flash?

Tags: android, decryption, smartphone

I have an old phone that I am trying to recover the data from. I was hoping to desolder the chip and buy an expensive reader for NAND flash chips but then it occurred to me that the contents of the flash chip are probably encrypted. If I am able to successfully remove the flash chip and extract its contents, could I theoretically write some software that decrypts it by reading the Android source code? Am I grossly missing something that makes this impossible?

Comment: What you are describing is called chip-off attack which doesn't work on android and iOS because their encryption keys are cryptographically tied to onboard **Trusted Execution Environment** chip.

Comment: You can [try this script](https://github.com/mspreitz/MobileForensics/blob/master/AndroidForensics/FDE/crypto_footer.py) if your device is so old that it doesn't have a TEE chip.